# i want to declare first name full and last name but giving error in this java program

Tags: java, compiler-errors, helper

can anyone please help me in finding the error.I am
 beginner[its showing an error in string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkeAF.png)

Comment: First: add code as text not as link to an Image. Second: use a Debugger to find out what is happening

Comment: `Scanner.next()` returns the next **word**, there will be no spaces inside the result...

Comment: This is surely already answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 1):

The call to indexOf(space) on line 9 returns -1 (indicating the string was not found), you can see that in the error message. And thus you try to call cname.substring(0,-1) which throws the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

So either you have to check the index before using it in the substring method, or you have to make sure it does not return -1.